# Make appearance of one svg change based on action taken in other svg

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a webpage and I have two svg's. One is a timeline of events; I would like it so that they user can click on an event on the timeline and have additional information appear in the second svg.

However, I'm at a loss as to how get this specific information into the second svg. This the code that I'm using to create the events on the timeline. I've set this up so that on click, it will do something (but I'm not having luck transferring a sliver of data to the other svg, nor am I sure that the way I'm even calling the other svg works; I'm extremely inexperienced with js/d3).

```
  g.selectAll('.circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'point')
    .attr('cx', d => x(d.date))
  .attr('cy', d => (50-(d.amount) * 10))
  .attr('r', 6)
  .style('fill', d => (d.color))
  .style('fill-opacity', 1.0)
  .on('mouseover', d => console.log(d))
  .on('click', more_info);

function more_info () {
    var svg = d3.select('#timelineinfo');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `more_info`, `d3.js` will magically pass the parameters `d` (data) and `i` (index) from that specific `circle` element. Assuming you've put all the 'extra data' into your `data` variable which you bound to the `circle` elements, you can get that data in your `more_info` function. All you need to do is add the parameters like so:

```
function more_info (d, i) {
    doSomething(d.extradata);
}
```